# ¿Cómo aplicar el estilo dentro de un div class container con css?

Tags: html, css3

Muy buenas, para explicar bien la pregunta, no comprendo bien cómo dar estilo de esta forma como esta imagen: [image: Ejemplo]

Soy aún novato en el estilo CSS, pero no lo comprendo bien. Utilizo el formato HTML usando Bootstrap, este es mi código:

**contact.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
 <head>
 <title>Bootstrap Ejemplo</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
 <h4>Contactanos</h>
 <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Telefono" name="telephone">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Mensaje" name="message">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Enviar">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando investigué, solo revisé que en css se permite usar div, no con class=containers. Si se dan cuenta, solo logré crear un botón con azul diferente que la otra imagen.
Espero pronto sus respuestas para aclarar bien sobre como aplicar bien el 
formato css.

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres lograr? Tu código se ve bien. ¿Deseas poner "contáctanos" a la izquierda y no encima? O solo aplicar colores?

Comment: exactamente así y el fondo del color, no sé como aplicarlo en css en el caso del container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola bueno para tu caso para poder replicar tu caso puedes hacer que lo elementos se alinean con la clase `row` de bootstrap, para luego trabajar con el sistema de rejillas de este como son los `col-*`, la forma de poder hacer esto sería tal que así.

```css
.bg-warning {
  background-color: #ffc446 !important;
}

.border-0 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.espacios {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.rounded-circle {
   -webkit-border-radius: 20% !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 20% !important;
  border-radius: 20% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Ejemplo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row espacios bg-warning">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        <h4>Contactanos</h>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
        <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" name="name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control border-0" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control border-0" name="phone" placeholder="Telefono" name="telephone">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" id="message" placeholder="Mensaje" name="message">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle" value="Enviar">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El código anterior hace que puedas usar las rejillas de forma que mas te acomode, es una de las formas a mi criterio mas sencillas , para que logres ver bien esto pon este snnipet en pantalla completa.Agregué también algunos estilos, la clase de css `.bg-warning` es para darle de color al fondo, la clase `.border-0` la use para quitarles los bordes redondos al los inputs , la clase `espacios` la use para que el espacio entre el contenido y los limites del div y que no se encuentren, en otras palabras tiene ese div tiene relleno y por último la clase `rounded-circle` que permite tener cierta curvaturas para el botón, ahí edita lo como te gustes.

> PD: Coloqué la clase `col-xs-12` y `col-sm-12` por que no tiene sentido poner ese formulario para dispositivos mas pequeños, por aquí lo importante es el `col-md-2` y `col-md-10` que es el que hace posible que se forme como quieres, los otros son col- `lg` y `xl` pero ya eso queda a tu criterio.

Saludos. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Ahora comprendí muy bien por la clase de bootstrap y el sistema de rejillas.
Muchas gracias por esta respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias crear otro archivo llamado "mis-estilos.css" y ponerlo en donde se encuentran los demas archivos .css

Dentro de este archivo vas a tener que crear la siguiente clase

`.footer-color { background-color: orange };`

Luego desde el HTML tendrias que importar el nuevo archivo css que creaste

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="mis-estilos.css">`

Y agregarle la clase al div

`<div class="container footer-color">`

Comment: gracias por esta respuesta, es justo que buscaba, es como el id para que pueda leer el .css!

Comment: En realidad es un selector de clase, los selectores de CLASE los definis anteponiendo un `.` y los selectores de ID los definis con `#`. (https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diferencias-class-id/)